# Why does Emacs swap Backspace and Delete on this one machine?

Tags: key-bindings, linux, x11

One of my key bindings is not working on one particular machine and I don't understand why.

On Ubuntu 14.04, with the `emacs24` package version `24.3+1-2ubuntu1`, I start `emacs -Q` (under X) and run

```
(global-set-key [(meta backspace)] 'undo)
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>.

On machine 1, I see as expected that

```
<M-backspace> runs the command undo
```

On machine 2, I see

```
M-DEL (translated from <M-backspace>) runs the command backward-kill-word
```

The machines are running the same distribution and should be configured pretty much identically. The Emacs packages are the same, yet they react differently even under `emacs -Q`.

After a bit of investigation, it turns out that the culprit is `input-decode-map`, which on machine 2 contains

```
(keymap
 (27 keymap
     (C-backspace .
          [27 C-delete])
     (C-delete .
           [27 C-backspace]))
 (C-M-backspace .
        [C-M-delete])
 (C-M-delete .
         [C-M-backspace])
 (M-backspace .
          [M-delete])
 (M-delete .
       [M-backspace]))
```

On machine 1, the keymap contains the same keys, but they're all bound to `nil`.

1. **Why does `input-decode-map` exchange <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> on machine 2?**
2. How do I fix this? I can obviously remove the entries, but there may be terminals where it's warranted; how do I change `input-decode-map` on X11 only (keeping in mind that I do sometimes open terminal and X11 frames in the same instance, so testing `window-system` in `.emacs` isn't good enough)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that <kbd>Delete</kbd> (`delete`) is also translated to `DEL` rather than `deletechar`; this happens in `local-function-key-map`, not in `input-decode-map`, so I didn't notice it at first because my keybindings overrode that.

The manual has a section [“If <DEL> Fails to Delete”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html#DEL-Does-Not-Delete), which pointed me to `normal-erase-is-backspace`, which is used when a frame is created in the function `normal-erase-is-backspace-setup-frame` from `simple.el` and `normal-erase-is-backspace` has the value `maybe` (that last is the case on both machines). For X11, this calls the native function `x-backspace-delete-keys-p`.

> Check if both Backspace and Delete keys are on the keyboard of FRAME.
>   FRAME nil means use the selected frame.
>   Value is t if we know that both keys are present, and are mapped to the
>   usual X keysyms.  Value is `lambda` if we cannot determine if both keys are
>   present and mapped to the usual X keysyms.

Looking at the C implementation, it uses XKB and tests whether the physical key `DELE` sends the keysym `Delete` and the physical key `BKSP` sends the keysym `BackSpace`. This is normally the case, but machine 2 is a laptop with cursor keys placed awkwardly, and I used xmodmap to shuffle a few keysyms around including `Delete`. Thus on machine 2 `DELE` doesn't send `Delete`, so `x-backspace-delete-keys-p` returns `nil`, so `normal-erase-is-backspace-setup-frame` calls `normal-erase-is-backspace-mode` with the argument 0, which causes this undesired remapping (`delete` to `DEL` in `local-function-key-map`, `M-backspace` to `M-delete` in `input-decode-map`, etc.).

One fix would be to use XKB rather than xmodmap to shuffle my cursor keys, and declare the physical keys `DELE` and others as having different keycodes, rather than declare the keycodes to have different keysyms. See [my follow-up question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb).

Inside Emacs, my blunt fix for now is to force `x-backspace-delete-keys-p` to return `t`.

```
(when (subrp (symbol-function 'x-backspace-delete-keys-p))
  (fset 'builtin-x-backspace-delete-keys-p
        (symbol-function 'x-backspace-delete-keys-p))
  (defun my-x-backspace-delete-keys-p ()
    t)
  (defalias 'x-backspace-delete-keys-p 'my-x-backspace-delete-keys-p)
  (if (eq window-system 'x)
      (mapc (lambda (frame)
              (when (frame-parameter frame 'display)
                (set-terminal-parameter frame 'normal-erase-is-backspace nil)
                (normal-erase-is-backspace-setup-frame frame)))
            (frame-list))))
```

Answer (score -1):

When you see <kbd>DEL</kbd> in Emacs-land, it doesn't mean the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, it means the backspace control character (so it's [almost] synonymous with backspace).

From the doc string of `(edmacro-mode)` (which defines the keys that `kbd` uses):

> - The special words RET, SPC, TAB, DEL, LFD, ESC, and NUL represent
>     special control characters.  The words must be written in uppercase.
> - A word in angle brackets, e.g., , , or , represents
>     a function key.  (Note that in the standard configuration, the
>     function key  and the control key RET are synonymous.)
>     You can use angle brackets on the words RET, SPC, etc., but they
>     are not required there.

So Emacs is not swapping anything, you're just confused because it's key naming scheme is a bit odd.

`backward-kill-word` is the default binding for <kbd>M-DEL</kbd>. So, while I'm not exactly sure why your specific `global-set-key` isn't working on one machine (could be a weird keyboard or keyboard layout), I would bet that the following does:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-DEL") 'undo)
```

If not, try using `(kbd "M-<backspace>")`. In general, using `kbd` is almost always better than trying to figure out how to write the keys manually with the proper escapes, codes, etc. It's more readable and consistent.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm way ahead of you. I know what `DEL` means (it's not what you say, by the way: it means character 127, which may or may not be backspace depending on the terminal configuration). Emacs *is* swapping some keychords involving `backspace` with corresponding keychords involving `delete`, via `input-decode-map`. My `global-set-key` isn't working because `input-decode-map` acts at a lower level. I don't want to set `M-DEL` to `undo`, I want to set `M-backspace` to `undo` (it would make a difference on a terminal frame).

Comment: *(cont.)* `kbd` is more convenient than writing keys manually, but there's no reason to use it, and indeed in subtle cases it's an extra level of indirection that's best avoided. When I write `M-backspace`, I mean what I write.